# Load different versions/instances of a table from another worksheet (Excel VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, user-interface, user-controls

To explain I'll start by presenting the problem and then my current approach (currently just an idea) for doing this. However I'm happy for my idea to be proven rubbish, so don't let my approach limit your answer. 
I have a group of projects and each project has its milestones and therefore a milestones table. The table will look like this:

```
    Project
    Milestone  |  Date   |  Status
----------------------------------------
    Milestone 1| 1.4.14  |  Complete
    Milestone 2| 1.4.15  | In Progress

etc.
```

Each project would need its own table of this format.

**Goal**: Rather than have a sheet per table (or table per project) I would like to make it so the user isn't overwhelmed by a worksheet (or even table) for every project.
**My Solution :** Just a rough idea but I was thinking I could have one main table that the user reads/edits with buttons either side allowing you to switch to the next projects table.
 All these tables' values would be stored in a dummy sheet (hidden) and the macro would change the cell references on the main table. So essentially the dummy table would have (3* number of projects) columns filled. I'm not sure if this is the best way to achieve what I want and would greatly appreciate some help. Feel free to ask any questions.

Answer (score 1):

Although you appear to only have one record per project I still find it preferable to uniquely identify with a number instead of a potentially random length text field. I would recommend creating your hidden sheet that contains this table but to include a 4th column. 
You could add 1 column to that table that represents "Project ID".
Then you could store all of the data for each project in 1 table and just give each record pertaining to a specific project the specific project's unique ID.

Tab: Project Table (Hidden)

### ID    |  Milestone  |  Date   |  Status

```
1    |  blah       | 1.4.14  |  Complete
2    |  blah       | 1.4.15  | In Progress
```

You could use your buttons, I imagine a "Previous" & "Next" which would increase or decrease the project ID by one and pull in all of the data from the [Project Table] that equals that specific project ID. You could also use a ListBox to contain the name of each project so the user just clicks whichever one is the one they are looking for.

Doing it this way also allows you to have multiple milestones per project.
Tab: Project Table (Hidden)

### ID    |  Milestone  |  Date   |  Status

```
1    |  blah       | 1.4.14   |  Complete
1    |  blah       | 11.4.14  | In Progress
2    |  blah       | 1.4.15   | In Progress
```

For help with adding a ListBox to a worksheet please look here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/add-a-list-box-or-combo-box-to-a-worksheet-HP010236681.aspx